# Ansible Filter to get a string value upon providing a list and conditional statement

Tags: ansible

How can I have a filter around a loop like this as the below loop is repetitive

```
- name: Set fact Location label href
  set_fact:
    loc_label_href: "{{ item.href | default('') }}"
  loop: "{{ labels_response['json'] }}"
  when: "item.value == 3"
```

**How will filter look? I need the o/p in string**
The below is not working

```
class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'get_href': self.get_href,
        }

    def get_href(self, variable):
        return [item.href for item in my_list if item.value == variable)]
```

Error
`get_href() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"}`

I am calling it like this

```
set_fact:
  loc_label_href: "{{ labels_response['json'] | get_href(3) }}"
```

where, 3 is the variable in filter function.

Answer (score 0):

There is really 3 arguments provided: self, my_list, and variable.

Made `get_href` static method to not include self argument and add other argument to pass `my_list`.

Comment: With static method I am having to use filter method directly and may have to use lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this.

Filter method

```
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'get_href': self.get_href,
        }
    def get_href(self, my_list, a_variable):
        href_id = ""
        for item in my_list:
            if item['value'] == a_variable:
                href_id = item['href']
                break
        return href_id
```

Calling it as

```
- set_fact:
    app_label_href: "{{ labels_response['json'] | get_href(app) }}"
```

One of the other things was Python did not like `item.href` It needed to be called as `item['href']`.